# Merge 2 tables in MySQL with some duplicate data

Tags: mysql

I need to merge 2 tables with the same structure, `table1` and `table2`. They have mostly different rows, but some rows are duplicates.

Is there a way to merge `table2` into `table1` but leave out the duplicate records in 1 statement?

I'm quite new to MySQL to any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The query I have so far is just this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

So I don't know how to selectively leave out the duplicates.

Comment: should we guess your queries ?

Comment: @echo_me He talks about a principle, I think that there is no need for queries in his question.

Comment: @echo_me I'm not exactly sure what the query should be. The only thing I have so far is `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2`, but I don't know how to leave out the duplicate records.

Comment: You may have a good reference at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the results:

```
select * from table1 union select * from table2;
```

The union will remove the duplicates.

If you want to create a new table with the results:

```
create table merged_table
    select * from a1.t1 
    union 
    select * from a2.t1;
```

---

You can then:

```
drop table table1;
rename table merged_table to table1;
```

(Don't drop the table while other queries are or could be accessing it.)

Comment: how do I get this to check for duplicates from certain columns? Each table currently have their own IDs, so comparing using ID would not result in any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `INSERT SELECT` , in order to merge table2 into table1

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] table2 [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT * FROM table1
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: how does this deal with the duplicates?

Comment: If I had the `ID` column of these tables to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and then assigned that as the `PRIMARY KEY`, is there a way to check for duplicate using other columns during this process?